# What's the difference in 'personalize' and 'personalise'?

Tags: word-difference

Which usage is correct?

```
I want to personalize my webpage
I want to personalise my webpage
```

Comment: Question like this can be searched on any dictionary. 'ize' and 'ise' is just an American and British way of writing it. A lil' homework is needed before we ask anything on this big board.

Comment: Have you looked either *personalize* or *personalise* up in a dictionary? What did it say? If you're still confused after looking them both up and writing what you're still confused about, flag the question and I'll reopen it; but as it stands this question is off-topic for ELL.

Answer (score 7):

Before I explain this, in answer to your question, the correct choice is the one for the country you're residing in (or where your readers are from). If you're in a Commonwealth country, then it's probably *personalise*, if you're in the US, it's personalize.

This is related to etymology. All of these words are of both French and Latin origin, with the US preferring *Latin* and the UK preferring *French* spellings.

It's just a difference in American and British English spellings.

They mean the same thing. There are several variants in English spelling.

For words that end in *-ise* in British English, they're spelled *-ize* in the US. This is not universal though (e.g. it's still exercise in both).

Words ending in *-re* end in BrE are spelled *-er* in BrE (e.g. litre (Br); *liter* (Am)).

There are words that end in *-our*--e.g. colour--in UK English, are spelled as *-or*--e.g., color--in American English.

There are very many more, but this is very broad. Those are the biggest differences.